# __irq and __irq_XXXX keywords in ARM programming

Tags: arm, irq

According to the ARM manual, __irq is a keyword defining the interrupt handlers in C code. However, I am not clear what would do keywords like:

```
 __irq_arm
 __irq_arm_ramfunc
 __irq_XXXX
 .....
```

HOWEVER,
after reviewing the original of the code, it was pretty clear that there are spaces between __irq and __arm, as well as between __irq and __ramfunc. Therefore, my question is no longer valid. One should always look the code on the screen, instead from some handouts ...

Comment: A web search for +"__irq_arm_ramfunc" turns up literally only this question and nothing else - what's the context here? Are you sure these are actual keywords and not just some macros defined in a particular project?

Comment: They are not standard keywords. It will depend on your compiler.  Usually "ramfunc" pragmas mean that the function will run from RAM instead of flash memory, so the linker will copy the function from flash to RAM upon boot up.

Comment: Yes, I am reading through some code. And I did search google too. To be more precise, my question is is related to whether adding something after "__irq" would change something or not.

Comment: Thank to Mark Lakata, I resolved my question (see the edit above)